# How can I display the contents of a Parse cloud code array?

Tags: ios, arrays, parse-platform

I have an array in the Data Browser that is supposed to have a list of users who've received an item from a user. The actual content of the tile is 
`[{"__type":"Pointer","className":"_User","objectId":"3zQoMVRJOx"}]`

I can't figure out how to actually call,use, and display this data from Xcode.

My end goal is to be able to find the total number of users who've been sent an item so this is why I need the content from the array. Any help would be great. Im sure it is probably a simple line of code that I'm not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

Your question actually qualifies for a "too broad" flag, as it seems you haven't tried this yourself and are experiencing problems, but are asking us to supply the code for you. It is not just a simple line of code.

However, I will supply you with code snipped from the ios guide over at Parse, slightly altered to get the array you're after:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"GameScore"];
[query whereKey:@"playerName" equalTo:@"Dan Stemkoski"];
[query includeKey:@"receivers"]; // Force parse to include the user objects of receivers
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
  if (!error) {
    // The find succeeded.
    NSLog(@"Successfully retrieved %d scores.", objects.count);
    // Do something with the found objects
    for (PFObject *object in objects) {
        // Write to log the email of every receiver
        for (PFUser *receiver in object[@"receivers"]) {
            [receiver fetchIfNeeded]; // fetches the object if it is still just a pointer (just a safety; it should be already included by the includeKey call earlier in the code
            NSLog(@"Receiver: %@", receiver[@"email"]);
        } 
    }
  } else {
    // Log details of the failure
    NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
  }
}];
```

Good luck :-)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. However the receiving data is not in the user class. Do you know how to pull it from a different class?

Comment: No user class here. This is from the GameScore class. Replace that with your classname. The "user" objects are fetched from the "receivers" array you mentioned.